# Mount encrypted volume before / during login

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, encryption, user-accounts

To reduce impact of possible computer theft, I would like to have my user profile protected using a robust encryption, so that even if someone can get a physical access to my computer, he will not be able to read my data.

I am running Windows 7 Professional.

As I understand it, Windows 7 user profiles are [not secure against an attacker having access to the system](http://ask-leo.com/does_having_a_password_on_my_windows_login_keep_me_secure.html), as he is easily able to boot the system with another OS disk to get administrator access to the system.

I know one option could be to upgrade to Ultimate edition to use [BitLocker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitLocker_Drive_Encryption), but upgrading seems difficult, as Anytime upgrade is not working in my country and one needs to find a retailer who would still be selling Windows 7 upgrade. I would therefore prefer to find a 3rd party solution.

Another possibility would be to use TrueCrypt to protect the whole system partition, but that seems a bit extreme to me - I would need to repartition my disk to provide a new unencrypted boot partition, and I am also not quite confident what might be the performance impact of such solution, or how well would TrueCrypt play with the RAID 1 I am using on my system disk.

What I am looking for is something which would protect my user profile, but nothing more.

What I have found some far is a possibility to [mount a TrueCrypt volume before login](https://superuser.com/questions/436205/how-to-automount-a-truecrypt-volume-before-login-in-windows-7), however this has a serious drawback: the password is stored on the computer, therefore it does not fit intended purpose of protecting the data in case of the computer theft.

Is there any solution for this? I would prefer Open Source solution, but I do not exclude a commercial one if it works really well.

Comment: Related to http://superuser.com/questions/615807/using-truecrypt-for-encrypting-user-profiles-on-another-volume/701041#701041, but not the same, as I do not want to use encryption for the system volume.

Comment: Also related to http://superuser.com/questions/633120/how-can-i-encrypt-my-users-drive?rq=1

Comment: Almost duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/244844/encrypting-a-users-directory-in-windows-7